# Google maps and Jquery is showing only few points

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i am trying to make my custom points in google map (over 2 500 adresses) and google maps is showing only few points. Does anyone knows, where is a problem?

I am sorry for my czech notes in code.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true_or_false
    &amp;key=AIzaSyAgq2BmPYqJUF85Jk9-zrja22N3cpe_LfM"
    type="text/javascript">
  </script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    onload = function() {
        loadMap();
    }

  </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
var zoom = 10;
// definice vzhledu ikony (špendlíku) na mapě
var baseIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
baseIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
baseIcon.shadow = "";
baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
baseIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(20, 34);
baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(20, 2);

function initialize() {
  // zobrazení základní prázdné mapy
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(49.938402, 17.903719), zoom);
    map.setUIToDefault();
  }
}

// Vytvoření značek s písmennými indexy
function createMarker(point, index, address, name, mark) {
  // Vytvoření ikony (špendlíku) s písmenkem
  var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + index);
  var letteredIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
  letteredIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
  // Vytvoření GMarkerOptions objektu
  markerOptions = { icon:letteredIcon };
  map.setCenter(point, zoom);
  var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<b>" + name + "</b><br />" + address + "<br /><i>" + mark + "</i>");
  });
  return marker;
}



// Umístění několika značek

/* Tohle je vzor, jak to musí vypadat:
        pro města s ulicemi:
 showAddress("Jarkovická,50/7,74601,Opava");
        pro města bez ulic:
 showAddress("64, 746 01, Stěbořice");*/

function markers() {

    //adresses

showAddress("Akátová,455,74731,Velké Hoštice");
showAddress("Akátová,455,74731,Velké Hoštice");
showAddress("Albertovec,292,74728,Štěpánkovice");
showAddress("Albertovec,297,74728,Štěpánkovice");
showAddress("Albertovec,297,74728,Štěpánkovice");
showAddress("Albertovec,297,74728,Štěpánkovice");
showAddress("Alejní,378/26,74721,Kravaře");
showAddress("Alejní,702/1,74721,Kravaře");
showAddress("Alejní,728/13,74721,Kravaře");
showAddress("Almužnická,182/2,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Almužnická,182/2,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,1494/8,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,1496/10,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,1496/10,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,1503/18,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,2850/25,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,2850/25,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Anenská,2850/25,74601,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Dvořáka,1363/16,74801,Hlučín");
showAddress("Antonína Dvořáka,1456/25a,74801,Hlučín");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1214/22,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1216/26,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1227/10,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1242/4,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1393/7,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1395/11,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1395/11,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1517/39,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Sovy,1517/39,74705,Opava");
showAddress("Antonína Vaška,207,74792,Háj ve Slezsku");
showAddress("Antonína Vaška,207,74792,Háj ve Slezsku");
showAddress("Antonína Vaška,207,74792,Háj ve Slezsku");
showAddress("Antonína Vaška,73,74792,Háj ve Slezsku");
showAddress("Antonína Vaška,86,74792,Háj ve Slezsku");
showAddress("Osvobození,492,74757,Slavkov");

}

function showAddress(address, index, name, mark) {

  geocoder.getLatLng( //funkce ktera z adresy udela souradnice 

    address, 

    function(point){ 
      if (point) {
        map.addOverlay(createMarker(point, index, address, name, mark)); 
      } 

    } 

  );

}

</script>



<body onload="initialize();markers();"></body>

     <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>
  <div id="searchcontrol"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using the deprecated and turned off [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1), that should not be used for new code.

Comment: (1.) Why are you geocoding the same address multiple times?  That is wasteful of Google's resources.  (2.) The client geocoder will only work for about 10 addresses before running into the quota/rate limits, geocode that addresses offline and "cache" the result to use when loading your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client geocoder will only work for about 10 addresses before running into the quota/rate limits, geocode your addresses offline and "cache" the results to use when loading your page.

See [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) in the "articles" section of the documentation.